# How to initialize private members of a class using a friend function in C++?

Tags: c++, private-members, friend-function

I have written simple code in cpp as shown below. I am accessing private data members using 2 ways. First by using get an set method and next by using friend function. But for friend function I am getting garbage value for data members of an object. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    int roll_no;
    string name;
    public:
        void set(int r, string n)
        {
            roll_no = r;
            name = n;
        }
        void get()
        {
            cout<<roll_no<<" "<<name<<endl;
        }
        friend void access(Student s);
};

void access(Student s)
{
    s.roll_no = 5;
    s.name = "Shivansh";
}

int main()
{
    Student s;
    s.set(10,"Shrut");
    s.get();
    Student s1;
    access(s1);
    s1.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void access(Student s)` This takes its argument by value, so what it modifies is only a *copy* of the object. To have it actually modify `s1`, change the function to take the argument by reference.

Comment: `access(Student s)` -> `access(Student & s)`

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that your function takes the Student by value. (it copies it) In order for it to modify the Student object it has to take it by reference.

```cpp
// take it by reference to modify the Student.
void Access(Student& s) {
     s.roll_no = 5;
     s.name = "Shivansh";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the class object by reference in order to access the object and change the object's contents i.e. in your case the roll no. and name. Not doing so will result in invoking the default copy constructor and creating a copy of the
object.

```
access(Student &s)
{
 //Change object s
}
```

Read more about pass by reference and pass by value here
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-and-returning-objects-in-c/amp/